# How to connect root of tree to first node ? c++

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I have a tree. it's a 8 sons tree at most.

structure of tree is :

```
Struct Tree{
NodeA * root;

struct NodeA{
Tabsons sons;
List words
};

typedef std::vector<NodeA *> Tabsons
```

What do i have to put into my root node?
For example this image:

[image]

it's a n-ary tree with pointer structures inside going into subnodes.

---

What is the content of this node?

[image]

Notes with empty data and the list of pointers?

Comment: If you don't know what's the data, who should know? And - are you sure your code compiles?

Comment: No i mean, i have data going from "a to z" in form of strings.
And for example If my root data is 'a' , any subnodes from this node will contain any words beginning by 'a'. But if my root is 'a' how do i get words beginning by 'b', 'c' etc. I was thinking of starting with a empty node but not sure if this is the way to do it.

Comment: I still don't get your problem. Why do you think that it is not a good way to leave the root node "empty"? This is what you should have elaborated in your question.

Comment: What about daughters?

Comment: Where's the end of the root node class?  Is the `NodeA` class defined int the `Tree` structure?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use a `std::vector<Node>` as your root node.
This will allow you to have one link to each letter in the alphabet.

So in your diagram, `vector['b']` would point to the try for the word "by".

The `vector['s']` would contain a link to a node that has another vector of links for the 2nd letter nodes.